# Using Fubini to obtain the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

For the volume of the n-dimensional unit ball $B_1(0) \subset \mathbb R_n$ one can write
$$
|B_1(0)| = \int_{B_1} 1 dx
$$

in [this document](https://www.uni-muenster.de/AMM/num/Vorlesungen/PDEI_SS14/material/PDEnotes.pdf) the author is using induction to obtain the volume but there is still one step which is confusing me:

For $n>2$ let $x \in B_1(0)$ then we can write $x=(x',x'')$ with $x'=(x_1,x_2)$ and $x''=(x_3, \dots, x_n)$ such that 
$$
x' \in D_1= \{ x \in \mathbb R ^2 : |x|<1 \}
$$
and
$$
x'' \in (B_1)_{x'} = \{x'' \in \mathbb R ^ {n-2} : (x',x'') \in B_1(0) \}
$$
Now the author is appealing Fubini's theorem:
$$
\int_{B_1} 1 dx = \int_{D_1} \int_{(B_1)_{x'}} dx''dx'
$$
For me this makes somehow geometrically sense (like e.g. the coarea formula for integrals) but a rigorous argument is missing.

Comment: I don't see why Fubini's theorem isn't a rigorous argument here.

Comment: I know that Fubini is valid for some product space. But what es the exact product space here. The expression $D_1 \times (B_1)_{x'}$ is dependent on x' ... do we use $B_1 = D_1 \times (B_1)_{x'}$?

Comment: Use the product space $\mathbb R^2\times\mathbb R^{n-2}$ and integrate the characteristic function of the ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the tips of Andreas Blass I understand the application of Fubini now. Here a quite detailed argument:

$$
\int_{B_1} 1(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} 1_{B_1}(x) dx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{B_1}(x_1, \dots,x_n)dx_3\dots dx_ndx_1 dx_2
$$
$$
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{ \{ x_3^2+\dots + x_n^2<1-x_1^2-x_2^2 \}}(x_1, \dots,x_n)dx_3\dots dx_ndx_1 dx_2
$$
$$
=\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} 1_{\{ x_1^2+x_2^2<1 \}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} 1_{ \{ x_3^2+\dots + x_n^2<1-x_1^2-x_2^2 \}}(x_1, \dots,x_n)dx_3\dots dx_ndx_1 dx_2
$$
$$
=\int_{D_1}\int_{(B_1)_{x'}} 1 dx''dx'
$$